# Why can I only access 7 of 16GB ram?

Tags: memory, ram

I have an FM2+ AMD A10-7700K APU build.

4 physical ram slots filled @ 4 gb each; total 16 gb

2 ssd drives; 120gb (containing OS) and 256gb data

I have been running Cinnamon Mint desktop on this machine for several years.

I just replaced the 120gb drive containing the OS with a new device.

I reinstalled Mint 19; standard normal.

Now I only see / system is using 6.9 GB of my 16 GB ram;

ie via terminal htop/top or desktop "system monitor" I see 6.9Gib

[image]
[image]

[image]

Curiously...

`lshw` returns 6909MiB

whereas `sudo lshw` returns 16GiB

How can I fix this so I can use the full amount of ram again?

here are pertinent diagnostics:

```
oracle@oracle:~$ lshw -C memory


WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-memory                  
       description: System memory
       physical id: 0
       size: 6909MiB
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.


oracle@oracle:~$ sudo lshw -C memory

  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 24
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: BLS4G3D18ADS3.16FE
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 0
          serial: 5951031B
          slot: DIMM_A1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: BLS4G3D18ADS3.16FE
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 1
          serial: 5951034A
          slot: DIMM_A2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: BLS4G3D1609DS1S00.
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 2
          serial: AD0195EA
          slot: DIMM_B1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: BLS4G3D1609DS1S00.
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 3
          serial: A015A6F5
          slot: DIMM_B2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 32
       slot: L1 CACHE
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 33
       slot: L2 CACHE
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2


oracle@oracle:~$ cat /proc/meminfo


MemTotal:        7075532 kB
MemFree:         1287176 kB
MemAvailable:    3876744 kB
Buffers:          132812 kB
Cached:          2756456 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2950656 kB
Inactive:        2380020 kB
Active(anon):    2397828 kB
Inactive(anon):   205576 kB
Active(file):     552828 kB
Inactive(file):  2174444 kB
Unevictable:          48 kB
Mlocked:              48 kB
SwapTotal:       7519228 kB
SwapFree:        7519228 kB
Dirty:               640 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2441496 kB
Mapped:           554940 kB
Shmem:            228476 kB
Slab:             219512 kB
SReclaimable:     159268 kB
SUnreclaim:        60244 kB
KernelStack:       10752 kB
PageTables:        65192 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    11056992 kB
Committed_AS:    9344292 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     14336 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      352868 kB
DirectMap2M:     6926336 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB



oracle@oracle:~$ egrep "model name|address" /proc/cpuinfo


model name  : AMD A10-7700K APU with Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
model name  : AMD A10-7700K APU with Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
model name  : AMD A10-7700K APU with Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
model name  : AMD A10-7700K APU with Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual


oracle@oracle:~$ uname -a


Linux oracle 4.15.0-70-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 10:36:11 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
oracle@oracle:~$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19
DISTRIB_CODENAME=tara
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 19 Tara"
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="19 (Tara)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 19"
VERSION_ID="19"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=tara
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory


oracle@oracle:~$ free


              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7075532     2759988     1274080      218636     3041464     3866492
Swap:       7519228           0     7519228



oracle@oracle:~$ sudo dmidecode -t memory


# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_A1
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Undefined       
    Serial Number: 5951031B  
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: BLS4G3D18ADS3.16FE
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_A2
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1866 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Undefined       
    Serial Number: 5951034A  
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: BLS4G3D18ADS3.16FE
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_B1
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Undefined       
    Serial Number: AD0195EA  
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum2
    Part Number: BLS4G3D1609DS1S00.
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_B2
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK3
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1866 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Undefined       
    Serial Number: A015A6F5  
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum3
    Part Number: BLS4G3D1609DS1S00.
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s


oracle@oracle:~$ lspci


00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1425
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)


oracle@oracle:~$ lspci -v -s 01:00.0


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia


oracle@oracle:~$ sudo lspci -v -s 01:00.0


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia


oracle@oracle:~$ glxinfo | egrep -i 'device|memory'


    GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_NV_swap_group, 
    GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 2048 MB
    Total available memory: 2048 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 516 MB
    GL_EXT_import_sync_object, GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, GL_NVX_nvenc_interop, 
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_memory_attachment, 
    GL_NV_register_combiners2, GL_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, 
    GL_NV_transform_feedback2, GL_NV_uniform_buffer_unified_memory, 
    GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
    GL_EXT_import_sync_object, GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, GL_NVX_nvenc_interop, 
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_memory_attachment, 
    GL_NV_register_combiners2, GL_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, 
    GL_NV_transform_feedback2, GL_NV_uniform_buffer_unified_memory, 
    GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
    GL_EXT_map_buffer_range, GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, 
    GL_NV_internalformat_sample_query, GL_NV_memory_attachment, 


oracle@oracle:~$ grep -i memory /var/log/Xorg.0.log


[     8.238] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[     8.284] (II) NVIDIA: Using 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[     8.372] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
```

Comment: ok so you mean this is an "old" machine having préviously 16GB & all ram worked ?

Comment: yes this is an "old" machine; previously working.  the only change was drive containing "only the os" and fresh os install.   was certainly running all 16 gigs up until the swap.

Comment: Could it be a user memory quota issue? Notice that commands issued with sudo show the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

In the end... I swapped the RAM in question to another machine.  Its dead there too.  Seems it was a physical hardware issue.   Somehow I must have toasted it when I did the SSD swap?   Weird.   Thanks for the help!